# loop through array of objects

Tags: php

I Have an array called $pages content is as follows:

```
Array
(
[01-about-us] => Page Object
    (
        [_uri] => about-us
        [_menuItem] => 01
        [_visable] => 1
    )

[02-contact] => Page Object
    (
        [_uri] => contact
        [_menuItem] => 02
        [_visable] => 1
    )

[_sitemap] => Page Object
    (
        [_uri] => sitemap
        [_menuItem] => 
        [_visable] => 
    )

[home] => Page Object
    (
        [_uri] => home
        [_menuItem] => 
        [_visable] => 1
    )
)
```

is there an easy way to loop through and get page objects by there properties ie:

```
<?php foreach($pages->_visible() AS $p): ?>
  <li> page </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to only fetch objects that are visible in this case?

Comment: Just loop over the array normally and use an `if` statement inside the loop to determine whether each page object is visible and a list element should be rendered.

Comment: Two things: 1: you are inconsistently spelling `visible`. 2: in the array you refer to `visable` as a field, in the `foreach` as a method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. You will have to use an `if`:

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    if ($page->_visible == 1) {
        echo "<li>page</li>";
    }
}
```

(Note also you misspelt `visible` in the array, perhaps a typo?)

Comment: I think the leading underscore (`_...`) in the output indicates private properties... I did not work a lot with PHP lately though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling PHP has a `private` keyword for that. I couldn't tell if I do not have the class definition of the `Page` class of OP. He uses it in his own code, so I reckoned this is the way to know if a page is visible. It should probably use a method, though.

Comment: perfect thanks it was just a spelling problem i thought i was going crazy.

Comment: Ah, apparently private properties are suffixed with `:private`: http://codepad.org/6clkYH0u. nvm then :)

Answer (score 6):

Or you can utilize PHP's `array_filter` function:

```
$pagesVisible = array_filter($pages, function($page) {
    return (bool) $page->_visible;
});

foreach ($pagesVisible as $key => $page) {
    print '<li>' . $key . '</li>';
}
```

Or shorthand it to:

```
$filter = function($page) {
    return (bool) $page->_visible;
};
foreach (array_filter($pages, $filter) as $key => $page) {
    print '<li>' . $key . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to loop through the pages array and inside the loop access the object properties like:

```
<?php foreach($pages as $k => $p): ?>
   <?php if ($p->_visable === 1): ?>
   <li><?php echo $k; ?></li>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please note that **visable** is misspelled but thats how it is in your question

Comment: Why all the `<?php` `?>` tags?

Comment: Because thats how the OP is currently doing it, YES I understand all about BEST PRACTICES but was trying to stick with their current structure ;)

Comment: When using PHP as template language, i.e. embedding PHP into HTML, then this style is more readable IMO than anything else. Each statement looks like a "tag" somehow and thus easier to spot / fits better into HTML and the structure / flow is clearer.