# How can add a value to array item and then increase?

Tags: php

I have one array:

```
$logins= array("login1", "login2", "login3"I;
```

I have an event where all login (login1, login2, login3) have access.

Now login1,login2,login3 can click on event unlimited times.

I will reduce the access to the event maximum 2 times.

here is the code:

```
function replaychargeClick($aseco, $command) {
global $replaycharge, $replaybills;


$coppers = $replaycharge['coppers'];
$playerid = $command[0];
$login = $command[1];
$answer = $command[2].'';
$aseco->client->query('GetDetailedPlayerInfo', $login);
$player = $aseco->client->getResponse();
$nickname = $player['NickName'];
    if ($answer == '234561') {
    $aseco->client->query('GetCurrentChallengeInfo');
    $thistrack = $aseco->client->getResponse();
    $aseco->client->query('GetNextChallengeInfo');
    $nexttrack = $aseco->client->getResponse();

    // Check if already being replayed
    if ($thistrack['FileName'] != $nexttrack['FileName']) { 
        //  Check for TMF server
        if ($aseco->server->getGame() == 'TMF') {
            // check for TMUF server
            if ($aseco->server->rights) {
                // check for TMUF player
                if ($player['OnlineRights'] >= 0 ) {

                    // start the transaction
                    $message = 'You need to pay '.$coppers.' coppers to replay the track';
                    $aseco->client->query('SendBill', $login, $coppers, $message, '');
                    $replaybillid = $aseco->client->getResponse();
                    $replaybills[$replaybillid] = array($login, $nickname, $coppers);
                } else {
                $message = formatText($aseco->getChatMessage('UNITED_ONLY'), 'account');
                $aseco->client->query('ChatSendServerMessageToLogin', $aseco->formatColors($message), $login);
                }
            } else {
            $message = formatText($aseco->getChatMessage('UNITED_ONLY'), 'server');
            $aseco->client->query('ChatSendServerMessageToLogin', $aseco->formatColors($message), $login);
            }
        } else {
        $message = $aseco->getChatMessage('FOREVER_ONLY');
        $aseco->client->query('ChatSendServerMessageToLogin', $aseco->formatColors($message), $login);
        }
    } else {
    $message = '>$f00 This track is already being replayed';
    $aseco->client->query('ChatSendServerMessageToLogin', $message, $login);
    }
}
```

}

So how can I add a counter for each login?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store counter for all the logins, just add a key in the array.

```
$loginsWithCount = array({
  key: "login1,
  count: 0
}, {
  key: "login2,
  count: 0
}, {
  key: "login3,
  count: 0
});
```

Now, you can update the count by looping through the array and finding the right login object and updating its count or for optimization you can create a hash and do it.

```js
$keyToUpdate = 'login1';
$countToUpdate = 10;

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item->key === $keyToUpdate) {
        $item['count'] = $countToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how can I  do this.

Comment: Can You explain me how can I increase the count to 2 by "login2" ?

Comment: I'm really beginner in PHP :)

Comment: help me please :(

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969469/loop-through-array-of-objects

Comment: i seen this, but not working for me. i would like increase the counter just one account, not on all. Example: Each login have 2 free access to the event. when login2 click on event , he have one more click. all other logins (login1, login3) must have 2

Comment: So need limited access to this function for logins

Comment: i didn't understand your question now